# Remove people suggestion in search result web part

Tags: 2013, search, people-search

I have a page that allows me search items of a specific contenttype, and only this content type.

My query is : `{?{searchboxquery} AND} ContentTypeID:0x012345678*`. Due to the search query, the components appends `-ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople` to the query.

This is working as expected, unless the search query match an account name. In this case, the people is suggested in the component :

[image: result]

How can I remove thie behavior? I tried to disable query suggestion both on the SearchBox component and on the result webpart, but the people suggestion is still here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Result Block from the Query Rule "People Name in People Search". You can turn it off. Probably a better alternative is to create a new result source for your queries to act on. Then none of the out of the box rules will apply.

1. Create the Result Source in the SSA, Site Collection, or site. Use the same query from above `{?{searchTerms} AND ContentTypeID:0x012345678*}`
2. Edit the Search Results Web Part and change the Query to use your Result Source.
3. Save, Check-in, and Publish the page.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Shouldn't the query in the result source be `{?{searchterms} AND} ContentTypeID:0x012345678*}` ?

Comment: You have an extra "{" and the AND is implied. `{?{searchterms}  ContentTypeID:0x012345678*}` alternatively you could also use the Name of the ContentType. `{?{searchterms} ContentType:Resume}`

Comment: Great! Glad it worked.